# How to add HighChart to Angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular8

I am trying to use Highchart in my angular project, but I keep getting the following error below everytime add it to "app.module.ts". Can someone show me how to resolve this?

> Failed to compile.
>
> src/app/app.component.html:14:3 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not
> a known element:
>
> 1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.
>
> 14   
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
> 5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

**The code app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HighchartsChartComponent } from 'highcharts-angular';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ListComponent,
    HighchartsChartComponent
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule ,      // add this
    HttpClientModule    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**I used the following command from this example https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-8-highcharts-example-tutorialexample.html to install "HighCharts"**

```
npm install highcharts --save
npm install highcharts-angular --save
```

**My angular Verson**

```
Angular CLI: 11.1.2
Node: 14.15.4
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.1.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1101.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1101.2
@angular-devkit/core            11.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.1.2
@schematics/angular             11.1.2
@schematics/update              0.1101.2
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.3
```

Comment: Share your `AppRoutingModule` and `app.component.html` code

Comment: there was nothing needed to be added for AppRoutingModule as per these examples for  Angular 8/9/10 https://therichpost.com/angular-8-9-10-highcharts-working-example. It giving error on addmodule before i can focus on app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you already imported `HighchartsChartModule` into your `app.module.ts`.

```
...
import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    HighchartsChartModule
```

Visit official documentation for more info: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#installing

Comment: Is there a step by step example using new Angular? I had tried that still gettign same errors

Comment: There should be no difference between Angular version of how to use the Highcharts. Please follow the documentation and import `HighchartsChartModule` as an `imports`.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular 
this is the official link for the module you are using and having the each steps clearly . please check this will help you to set up as simple highchart. working url https://codesandbox.io/s/lpn3yvv3zl?file=/src/app/app.component.html